# How to perform Request destination in user page

Tags: drupal, hook

I am trying to redirect any logged user attempts to access /user.

In my module the next code to redirect after login:

```
function ccmm_user($op, &$edit, &$account, &$category = NULL)
{
    switch($op){
        case 'login':
            $_REQUEST['destination'] = 'admin/';
            break;
    }
}
```

This is working. Then I try with *case 'view':* but it is useless.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the user to never get to the /user page, whether on login or even by going there manually.

In that case you should do a simple check in a hook_init function like this:

```
function ccmm_init() {
  if ( $_REQUEST['q'] == '/user' ) {
    drupal_goto('/admin'); // Or where ever you want to send them
  }
}
```

Of course there are a lot of checks you should do, and you may want to look into using the [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module, don't worry it's only 8k in size so the concern about adding yet another module is not such a problem in this case.

Comment: I don't know why, but that example is not working on my drupal (D6)..
Anyway, how users will to get login? (excuse my english :$)

Comment: fixed, change $_REQUEST['q'] -> arg(0)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Login Destination module](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) rather than writing your own code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not familiar with the [Login Toboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module, you should be.

Answer (score 0):

A better way could be to use `hook_menu_alter` in your module to just remove the menu entry for `/user/%user_uid_optional`, or move it to another URL.

That way you won't only be handling just logins (as you currently do), but ANY access to /user/ (caveat: including those by the admin user). Or you could use the same hook to modify the access check and only grant it to users with higher permissions, like `administer users`